# Arduino Mega 2560 - TFT 3.5 Display is not working with libraries suggested

Tags: arduino-mega

I attached two images of the shield.

[image: TFT Front image]

[image: TFT Back Image]

I bought an Arduino Mega 2560 R3 with a TFT 3.5 Display shield in China.

What I know from my research is:

1. There are no data sheets available in the Internet.
2. The factory's web site, in China, is in Chinese, and there is no information in English.
3. I achieved to know the factory is www.mcufriend.com, because it is the only reference in the shield.
4. Apparently the drive to use is R61581.
5. Using suggested libraries from Henning Karlsen (http://www.henningkarlsen.com/electronics/library.php)
   (UTFT, UTFT Geometry, tiny Fat, UTFT Tiny Fat, UTouch and UTFT buttons) . These libraries don't work with this shield.
6. Some people say that this shield requires 3.3 [Volts] to work, but the Vcc pin connected goes to 5V and it contains a Voltage regulator. I suppose it drops the voltage from 5[V] to 3.3[V] in the middle of the back side of the screen shield (see the upper photo - U1).
7. The specs that I found, say that this is a 262,144 Color 320x480 Dot Graphic LCD screen using a LCD driver a Si TFT Panel.
8. This screen includes a touch pad and a Micro SD memory reader.
9. After using the geometry test included in the library folder UTF Geometry mentioned on #5, and using all the drivers found in the documentation included by Henning Karlsen in a .pdf doc, I couldn't get this shield to work.

Does anyone know how to make this screen work?

I know is too much technology involved to be a fake shield, but it should be very useful to have this working. Do you agree with me?

Comment: In what way is it not working?

Comment: I drop down the testing software into the Mega, but the screen remains not showing any activity. Only the back light is on. I have an expensive lamp working, but it is not showing anything on it. I tried all the drivers.

Comment: The URL to the library mentioned in the OP's post is dead, and henningkarlsen.com appears to have moved to rinkydinkelectronics.com. The page may be now this one, [Library: UTFT](http://www.rinkydinkelectronics.com/library.php?id=51).

Answer (score 0):

I have the same display. It has ILI9137 chip using 8-bit mode, so original Henning Karlsen UTF library doesn't work. You can find this library patched to support this display using Arduino MEGA at https://github.com/dgolda/UTFT

If display wouldn't work it is probably broken. I've received first piece broken - only backlight was working, but second and third was OK.